# Finite order distributions

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $F$ be a linear functional on the space of test functions defined by $F(f)=\sum_{n\ge 0} f^{(n)}(n)$. show that $F$ is of infinite order.

Attempt: for any $f$ we have that $supp(f)$ is compact. Hence for some $N$, we have that $f(n)=0$ for any $n>N$. Hence the derivatives vanish as well. But I am ensure where to go from here since the norm is independent of the test function? (Here the norm is the one in the definition of the order of a functional)

Comment: Hint: What order has $F$ on $(n-\frac14, n+\frac14)$?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I assume it has order $n$? and then we choose another test function on the next interval (on as in compactly supported) shifted by 1 to show that it has order $n+1$. However I am unclear why it has order $n$, only the delta function satisfies that property.

Comment: On $(n-\frac14, n+\frac14)$ we have $F(f) = f^{(n)}(n) = (-1)^n \delta^{(n)}(f)$ so in fact, on that interval it is (up to a sign) a derivative of the Dirac delta.